# Dictionary where list is value as dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This may be an incorrect way to use dataframes, but I have a dictionary where the values are a list of items. Such as:

```
my_dict = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[3,4,5]}
```

I want to create a data frame where the indices are the keys and there is one column, where the value is the list. This is the output I'd like to see:

```
In [69]: my_df
Out[69]: 
              0
a     [1, 2, 3]
b  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is the closest I've gotten, by changing the dictionary value to a list of lists and using a transpose. What is the better way?

```
In [64]: my_dict = {'a':[[1,2,3]], 'b':[[3,4,5,6]]}

In [65]: my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

In [66]: print my_df
           a             b
0  [1, 2, 3]  [3, 4, 5, 6]

In [67]: my_df.T
Out[67]: 
              0
a     [1, 2, 3]
b  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you add the output you want...

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[3,4,5]}

pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in my_dict.values()],index=my_dict)
Out[3]: 
           0
a  [1, 2, 3]
b  [3, 4, 5]
```

But as what you have is more of a `Series` than a `DataFrame`:

```
pd.Series(my_dict)
Out[4]: 
a    [1, 2, 3]
b    [3, 4, 5]
```

and if you need to, you can convert it to a `DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_dict))
Out[5]: 
           0
a  [1, 2, 3]
b  [3, 4, 5]
```